# Get multiple elements from document.getSelection()

Tags: javascript

How can I get the multiple elements a user has selected from `document.getSelection()`?

```
document.getElementById("hello").onclick = function() {

  selection = document.getSelection();

  if(selection) {
     console.log(selection.anchorNode.textContent);
  }

};
```

http://jsbin.com/qisawudofa/edit?html,js,console,output

It seems to only return the element that was selected first, but in my case I need to get all of them.

Alternatively, is there a way to at least know when multiple elements have been selected?

Comment: You need to add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Use `document.getSelection().toString()`

Comment: @Andy i have supplied a jsbin

Comment: @mic4ael i need the elements selected, not the string

Comment: I don't have access to JSBin. But also, if JSBin were ever to die your question would be useless. Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @Andy ok have added the code

Answer (score 1):

You're probably most interested in the [`Ranges`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) that make up the selection. Remember the user can make multiple selections all over the page. Each continuous area of selection will get its own instance of `Range`.

You'll need to iterate over all of the ranges. For each of them you can see where it starts and where it ends:

```
if (selection) {
    for (i=0; i<selection.rangeCount; i++)  {
        range = selection.getRangeAt(i);
        if (range) {
            console.log(range.startContainer);
            console.log(range.endContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

But for the example described in your code you'll need to consider two more things:

1. Only if the user very accurately selects a paragraph will you get the paragraph's node in `startContainer`. They might start their start selection even one character after the beginning of the paragraph and then you'll get a text node with the paragraph as its parent.
2. The `Range` only gives you the start and the end of the selection for that range. It doesn't directly give you all of the elements in between. So if the user selects more than 2 paragraphs, you'll need to figure out exactly which paragraphs are between start and end yourself.